# seticon on sherlockactionbar while loading from another methode?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have layout java content map,I've already added new items in the right side of the action bar,the item show loading while map loading when oncreate..

[image]

i want to change menuitem to icon when map finish loaded..
here my code to make items loading.

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean isLight = SampleList.THEME == R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;
        menu.add("Icon").setActionView(R.layout.loading_lingkaran_kecil)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

        return true;
    }



@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapv2_main_activity);
        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                public void onMapLoaded() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "map has loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //here to make items stop show loading and change icon,but nothing happend with this code
                    getSupportActionBar().getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ico_member);


                }
             });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a boolean flag to check if it is done loading or not and call `invalidateOptionsMenu` to refresh your `onCreateOptionsMenu` while removing the **old icon** and replacing it with new Icon in the `OptionMenu`.

**sample:**

```
boolean doneLoading = false; //a global instance of the flag
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(!doneLoading)
        menu.add("Icon").setActionView(R.layout.loading_lingkaran_kecil).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    else
    {
        menu.removeItem(R.layout.loading_lingkaran_kecil); //will remove the old icon after the loading is done
        menu.add("Icon").setActionView(R.layout.you_new_layout_after_loading).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And in your `onMapLoadedCallback` you need to refresh the menu items in the actionbar setting the flag to true.

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                public void onMapLoaded() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "map has loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    doneLoading = true; //set to true means it is done loading
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); //refresh the optionsmenu

                }
             });
```

Comment: great... you save my time,,

Comment: @ltvie +1 this post as well, you are welcome and happy coding:))